# How to Calculate the "Drop Off" of a Set

Tags: probability, statistics

So I have never taken a formal class of statistics and this is likely just a case of me not knowing the right name for what I am looking for. Nonetheless, say I have a set of numbers in descending order like this:
$$
430, 390, 150, 140, 135...
$$
In my limited understanding of statistics, there is some sort of "drop off" from 390 to 140. **How can I calculate this "drop off" point and what is the name of this?**

Comment: What do you mean by "drop off" ?

Comment: Question unclear. Maybe you mean 'change point'.

Comment: Yes I guess. I'm not quite sure what the actual term is.